# Disabling primary selection outside of terminal

Tags: clipboard

I like the ability to highlight something in terminal, then go to some other application (e.g., Firefox) and paste what I've highlighted. Unfortunately, I have a lot of issues with primary selection.

### Example 1

I highlight some JSON in terminal that I want to paste in a website. I go to Firefox and highlight the URL, hit backspace and enter a new URL, I have now overwritten what I highlighted in terminal with the URL I just highlighted.

### Example 2

I highlight a chunk of code in Visual Studio Code, scroll down and highlight the chunk of code that I want to replace, then hit ctrl+v. Because my most recent highlight was the chunk of code I want to replace, not the code that I want to replace it with, I've now pasted the chunk of code that I want to replace, rather than the code above that I highlighted.

I'd like to retain the ability to highlight in terminal and have it go to primary selection for pasting outside of terminal, but in every other application I'd rather just disable highlight to copy (primary selection).

If nothing else, maybe I'm just doing something wrong here and someone knows a better way to deal with this.

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, I am also open to having the behavior of highlighting text in terminal copy to the primary clipboard. Just so long as highlighting outside of terminal does not do this. In many regards, I am looking for behavior similar to MacOS: highlight in iterm and it automatically is copied, cmd+v in firefox to paste it; highlight in firefox, must hit cmd+c to copy whatever is highlighted.

Comment: I am no expert, but there are two types of 'clipboard'. The one you are using is what I would call single use(deletes as soon as you copy again).  Think you would want a more permanent clipboard that keeps everything you copy(unless deleted by you).  Look in software store for clipboard and you might find something.

Comment: For Example 1, I have found that if you highlight text in the terminal and then Right-Click->Copy before switching to Firefox, it seems to work.

Comment: For Example 2, I don't have VS but in other editors, if you highlight text and ctrl-c and then highlight the text to replace and ctrl-v it seems to work.

Comment: Although it's not exactly what you've asked for, if someone knows how to make selection in specific applications (like the terminal) copy to the regular clipboard rather than behaving as primary selection, would that be a sufficient solution? I recommend that you **[edit]** your question to clarify that (especially if the answer is yes).

Comment: In the KDE clipboard, I think it's called klipper, There's a configuration checkbox for Ignore Selection. That solves your first two issues if your clipboard has a similar option. But, then, you have to use Ctrl+Shift+C to save highlighted text in your terminal into the clipboard and Ctrl+C elsewhere to do the same. If that's not good enough, you can use a tool such as AutoKey which will allow you to setup hotkeys that run scripts that do exactly what you want which can optionally be configured so that which script/behavior occurs is dependent on the active window title/class.